# Remove formatted displayed tax from order total line on WooCommerce emails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I would like to remove the formatted taxes displayed from order total line on emails notifications only.

I have tried the different answer code from [How to hide VAT label and value from WooCommerce order emails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32518807/how-to-hide-vat-label-and-value-from-woocommerce-order-emails), but none worked.

Here is a screenshot showing what I want to remove or hide:

[image: How to hide the tax price?]

Comment: check this answer here [How to hide VAT label and value from WooCommerce order emails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32518807/how-to-hide-vat-label-and-value-from-woocommerce-order-emails)

Comment: There are 3 codes, which one will I add? I'm confused :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following very simple code, to remove formatted taxes information from order line total on WooCommerce emails:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_formatted_order_total', 'change_emails_formatted_order_total', 10, 2 );
function change_emails_formatted_order_total( $formatted_total, $order ) {
    // Remove from order total the formatted taxes displayed on emails notifications only
    return is_wc_endpoint_url() ? $formatted_total : wc_price( $order->get_total(), array( 'currency' => $order->get_currency() ) );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**Addition:** To **display a custom text after** order line total amount replace:

```php
return is_wc_endpoint_url() ? $formatted_total : wc_price( $order->get_total(), array( 'currency' => $order->get_currency() ) );
```

simply by:

```php
return is_wc_endpoint_url() ? $formatted_total : wc_price( $order->get_total(), array( 'currency' => $order->get_currency() ) ) . ' ' . __("VAT included", "woocommerce");
```

Comment: thank you. it worked. but "VAT included" text will remain. could you please?

Comment: then, can you write a code that says "VAT included" next to the total amount?

Comment: (Are you asking to display after the price, the text "VAT included"?) Yes.

Comment: @SelmanGüneri I have updated my answer… See the addition.